# Are there any denominations that teach their members how to hear God's voice better, as exemplified by the Apostles in Scripture?

Tags: denomination-survey, christian-living, spiritual-gifts, spirituality, religious-education

From time to time I have come across people who claim to have heard the voice of God speak to them in various circumstances. To someone who has never experienced this firsthand, this may sound a bit crazy, but the Bible is not without examples where this phenomenon is reported to have happened to the apostles. For example:

2 Corinthians 12:7-10 (ESV):

> 7 So to keep me from becoming conceited because of the surpassing greatness of the revelations, a thorn was given me in the flesh, a messenger of Satan to harass me, to keep me from becoming conceited. 8 Three times I pleaded with the Lord about this, that it should leave me. 9 **But he said to me, “My grace is sufficient for you, for my power is made perfect in weakness.”** Therefore I will boast all the more gladly of my weaknesses, so that the power of Christ may rest upon me. 10 For the sake of Christ, then, I am content with weaknesses, insults, hardships, persecutions, and calamities. For when I am weak, then I am strong.

Acts 10:9-21 (ESV):

> 9 The next day, as they were on their journey and approaching the city, Peter went up on the housetop about the sixth hour to pray. 10 And he became hungry and wanted something to eat, but while they were preparing it, he fell into a trance 11 and saw the heavens opened and something like a great sheet descending, being let down by its four corners upon the earth. 12 In it were all kinds of animals and reptiles and birds of the air. 13 **And there came a voice to him: “Rise, Peter; kill and eat.”** 14 But Peter said, “By no means, Lord; for I have never eaten anything that is common or unclean.” 15 **And the voice came to him again a second time, “What God has made clean, do not call common.”** 16 **This happened three times, and the thing was taken up at once to heaven.**
>
> 17 Now while Peter was inwardly perplexed as to what the vision that he had seen might mean, behold, the men who were sent by Cornelius, having made inquiry for Simon's house, stood at the gate 18 and called out to ask whether Simon who was called Peter was lodging there. 19 And while Peter was pondering the vision, **the Spirit said to him, “Behold, three men are looking for you.** 20 **Rise and go down and accompany them without hesitation, for I have sent them.”** 21 And Peter went down to the men and said, “I am the one you are looking for. What is the reason for your coming?”

If the apostles experienced this, it is not far-fetched to think that Christians nowadays may also experience this. In light of this realization, I'd like to know (1) if there are any denominations that actually believe in this possibility (that God still speaks to people today), and if so, (2) if there are denominations that provide explicit teaching or training to their members on how to become more sensitive to God's voice to be able to hear Him better on a more consistent basis.

Comment: Catholics do so in a general manner, encourage the faithful to listen to God’s voice. But as to your question as to hearing God’s voice as exemplified by the Apostles in Scripture is a gift to those closely united to God in a genuine life of prayer. **”Hearken continually within thine heart, O son, giving attentive ear to the precepts of thy master.”** These are the opening words of the Prologue  to the [Rule of St. Benedict](https://www.solesmes.com/sites/default/files/upload/pdf/rule_of_st_benedict.pdf). And some Catholic saints have had this gift.

Comment: @Ken Graham any desire to make that an answer?

Comment: So Derek Prince when I used to listen to him, before certain issues, talked about it quite literally, “the rhema of God, the life quickened word.” Makes me wonder if Anglicans officially think it happens. Although he did not hesitate to believe what the Bible actually says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a principle of great importance to The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.

**Recent Teachings**

In an April 2020 global conference, church president Russell M Nelson gave a discourse entitled Hear Him, including the following remarks:

> We also hear Him more clearly as we refine our ability to recognize
> the whisperings of the Holy Ghost. It has never been more imperative
> to know how the Spirit speaks to you than right now. In the Godhead,
> the Holy Ghost is the messenger. He will bring thoughts to your mind
> which the Father and Son want you to receive. He is the Comforter. He
> will bring a feeling of peace to your heart. He testifies of truth and
> will confirm what is true as you hear and read the word of the Lord.
>
> I renew my plea for you to do whatever it takes to increase your
> spiritual capacity to receive personal revelation. (see [here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2020/04/45nelson?lang=eng))

Two years prior he also gave an address discussing how & why to come to recognize revelation from God. See [Revelation for the Church, Revelation for Our Lives](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2018/04/revelation-for-the-church-revelation-for-our-lives?lang=eng)

The April 2020 sermon led to a hashtag among Latter-day Saints #HearHim (referring to hearing God) that has prompted many responses in which people have described what they do to hear Him. My own #HearHim comments are [here](https://youtu.be/noRHUdDrOos).

**Passages from canonized scripture**

One of the Book of Mormon passages most commonly cited by missionaries of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints is Moroni 10:4-5, which specifically calls upon people to seek confirmation from God regarding the book:

> 4 And when ye shall receive these things, I would exhort you that ye
> would ask God, the Eternal Father, in the name of Christ, if these
> things are not true; and if ye shall ask with a sincere heart, with
> real intent, having faith in Christ, he will manifest the truth of
> it unto you, by the power of the Holy Ghost.'
>
> 5 And by the power of the Holy Ghost ye may know the truth of all
> things.

One of the passages used to describe what revelation from God feels like is Doctrine & Covenants 11:12-13:

> 12 And now, verily, verily, I say unto thee, put your trust in that
> Spirit which leadeth to do good—yea, to do justly, to walk
> humbly, to judge righteously; and this is my Spirit.
>
> 13 Verily, verily, I say unto you, I will impart unto you of my
> Spirit, which shall enlighten your mind, which shall fill your soul
> with joy;

**Conclusion**

Members of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe that God speaks today as He did in the past, and the church actively teaches its members to seek revelation from God for the areas of responsibility He has given them.

Comment: The lack of saying “among others” or even “i dont know if others do” lends a subtle but quite strong notion that this view is limited to them, eg the conclusion ~”I conclude lds does. QED.” when Catholics and others hold same.

Answer (score 1):

In the Lutheran tradition, a more nuanced approach is taken on the matter. That is to say there is the possibility of ongoing inspiration, but one must hear it (i.e. discern it) as a lower level of inspiration than the Scripture edited by the Old Testament Prophets & New Testament canonical Apostles.

For example, the 19th century Lutheran theologian Franz Pieper, writes in his Christian Dogmatics:

> The question has often been asked whether divine revelations
> pertaining to external events in Church or world might not be given to
> individual persons in our time. It does not contradict Scripture to
> admit the possibility and fact of such revelations. But it is contrary
> to Scripture to assume that new revelations on doctrine will be given;
> the revelation of doctrine has come to an end with the Word of the
> Apostles and Prophets. (Franz Pieper, Christian Dogmatics, Vol.1, p.
> 211)

After providing Biblical examples like Acts 11:27-28; 21:10-11, Franz Pieper also appeals to the Wittenburg theologian, Friedrich Balduin (1575-1627 A.D.):

> We do not doubt that God to this day at times reveals to men future
> things pertaining to the state of the Church or the State, to be
> announced for the use of men. (Christian Dogmatics, Vol, 1, p. 211)

Having said the above, Franz Pieper qualifies this by quoting the 17th century Wittenburg theologian, John Quenstedt:

> We must distinguish between revelations which pertain to, or attack,
> an article of faith, and those which concern the state of the Church
> or the State, social life, and future events; the first we repudiate;
> the latter, however, some hold, are not to be urged with any necessity
> of believing, nevertheless are not to be rashly rejected. (Franz
> Pieper, Christian Dogmatics, Vol. 1, p. 211)

The Lutheran position appeals to both Scripture and the early church's view of the continuation of low level inspirational prophetic gifts. For example, St. Jerome reacted to the Montanist movement in the early church by writing:

> ...if the Montanists reply that Philip’s four daughters prophesied
> (Acts xxi. 9) at a later date, and that a prophet is mentioned named
> Agabus, (Acts xi. 28; xxi. 10, 11 and that in the partition of the
> spirit, prophets are spoken of as well as apostles, teachers and
> others, we do not so much reject prophecy—for this is attested by the
> passion of the Lord—as refuse to receive prophets whose utterances
> fail to accord with the Scriptures old and new. - St. Jerome (385
> A.D., Letter XLI: To Marcella)